# Angular 2 trying to find a $broadcast like Angular 1.x had

Tags: angular

I was following the article in: https://blog.lacolaco.net/post/event-broadcasting-in-angular-2/

Problem is: it works, but only if the "sending"(`emitStringBroadcast`) & "receiving" (`registerStringBroadcast`) - are in the same component.

And I need them in two different components ( basically - I need to listen to an event fired from `sending_child.ts` - everywhere in my app )

Any ideas how `receiving_child.ts` can receive the msg ?

### broadcaster.ts

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface BroadcastEvent {
  key: any;
  data?: any;
}

export class Broadcaster {
  private _eventBus: Subject<BroadcastEvent>;

  constructor() {
    this._eventBus = new Subject<BroadcastEvent>();
  }

  broadcast(key: any, data?: any) {
    this._eventBus.next({key, data});
  }

  on<T>(key: any): Observable<T> {
    return this._eventBus.asObservable()
      .filter(event => event.key === key)
      .map(event => <T>event.data);
  }
}
```

### app.ts

```
// app.ts (application root component)
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    ...
    providers: [
        // application-shared broadcaster (similar to $rootScope)
        Broadcaster
    ]
})
class App {}
```

### sending_child.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'send-child'
})
export class SendComponent {
  constructor(private broadcaster: Broadcaster) {
  }

  emitStringBroadcast() {
    this.broadcaster.broadcast('MyEvent', 'some message');
  }
}
```

### receiving_child.ts

```
// child.ts
@Component({
    selector: 'receive-child'
})
export class ReceiveComponent {
  constructor(private broadcaster: Broadcaster) {
  }

  registerStringBroadcast() {
    this.broadcaster.on<string>('MyEvent')
      .subscribe(message => {
        ...
      });
  } 

}
```

Comment: Works fine here. http://plnkr.co/edit/R2kJ1EkENG4Ecu3cHNiY?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: wow, strange, let me check the diff

Comment: I'm not using the directives ( html tags ) as it's a component w/o a template, so I was trying to edit the plunker - but received a syntax error ( which I don't see any syntax error in my project itself ) http://plnkr.co/edit/Lan1JxfiCXXsjwldvefG?p=info

Comment: A component without a template doesn't make sense. The whole point of a component is to display something on the page. And of course, if you don't add the component to the page, then there is no instance of the component being created, so it can't send or receive anything. If you want something that doesn't display anything, but still does something, use a service, not a component.

Comment: But it's a "Timer" kind of thing, I don't need a tag in the HTML for it, specially because it's intended for the entire app vs a specific page in the app. I also don't understand why in my project, my component's properties is empty (`@Component({})` ) and my Plunker raise an SyntaxError ?

Comment: As I said, this should be a service, not a component.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to switch it, still I don't understand why for you it's working, and inside the project it doesn't .... will get back to you on that ! thanks

Comment: Please see working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/oXksLLoz7PSRAhqAPp9p?p=preview vs my non-working project example: http://plnkr.co/edit/Lan1JxfiCXXsjwldvefG?p=preview ... where the only thing different from your working code, is the `app.ts` -> `construct()` SendComponent declaration ... why do you think is the problem ?

Comment: The first one uses the component as if it was a service, by letting Angular create (and thus inject) the component, and inject the component in App. This works but is still wrong. Again, the component should be a service. The second one uses `new SendComponent` to create the component, thus passing nothing as argument to the constructor, which expects a broadcaster. So the broadcaster is undefined. This is horribly broken.

Comment: Got it, so this why if I pass `this.Timer = new SendComponent(this.broadcaster);` in `app.ts` it works ... but shouldn't be written like this. many many many thanks !